# where clause in group by

Tags: google-bigquery

The following query is working as expected.

```
select month, day, count(*) as cnt from publicdata:samples.natality
group by month,day 
order by cnt desc;
```

But as soon as I add **where year > 1990** 
I get only partial results. All the results match with the day = 0 but other days (1 to 31) are not listed in the results.
Is the query correct?

I will also like to know if I am paying for sample public data or it is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually seems like all data after 1989 have no other days than days set to 0 so the result you get is correct.

Comment: I need to group by only month + day. The purpose of this query is to find out the most "productive" month or day across all years.

Comment: Actually seems like all data after 1989 have no other days than days set to 0 so the result you get is correct.